# Passing all members of a case class to a Java method taking variadic arguments

Tags: scala, parameters, variadic-functions

Let's say I have a `case class CC(a: Int, b: String, c: Double)`.  For simplicity sake I'll limit it to 3 parameters but imagine I have many more, say 20.  My question is really about the larger example.

Now I have a Java `SQLServerDataTable` object that has an `addRow` method with the following signature:

```
public synchronized void addRow(Object... values) throws SQLServerException
```

I want to call `addRow` with all the parameters of the `CC` case class, but without having to list them all explicitly:

```
val cc = CC(1, "One", 1.0)
sqlServerDataTable.addRow( <some *-like magic with cc goes here> )
```

instead of:

```
sqlServerDataTable.addRow(cc.a, cc.b, cc.c)
```

not only because

```
sqlServerDataTable.addRow(cc.a, cc.b, cc.d, cc.e, ..., cc.theEnd)
```

gets tedious, but also I'm trying to find a way to generalize functions that use `addRow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't test it specifically with Java, but I assume that you need some combination of `_*` and `.productIterator`. The following compiles:

```
case class CC(a: Int, b: String, c: Double)
def addRow(xs: Any*): Unit = xs foreach println // just for demo
val x = CC(123, "123", 1.23)
addRow(x.productIterator.toSeq: _*)
```

will pass all components of `x` to `addRow` one by one:

```
scala> addRow(x.productIterator.toSeq: _*)
123
123
1.23
```

Comment: That looks very interesting, thanks, I'll experiment with that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need values from case class as a collection. Actually, every Scala `case class` extends `Product` which provides the method `productIterator`, which returns Iterator of every element of `case class`.

So maybe you're just looking for something like this?

```
sqlServerDataTable.addRow(cc.productIterator.toList:_*)
```

Comment: That looks very interesting, thanks, I'll experiment with that.

Comment: (I saw your answer just before I saw @AndreyTyukin's. Thank you both!)

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik Maybe I spent too much time creating an actually compilable example ;) Did the faster version work without `.toList: _*`, or did it just pass the entire `Iterator` as a single object?

Comment: I forgot to add `_*`, so my answer was incorrect :) So you were first with the right answer.